How to hide View Account Hierarchy icon from Highlights pannel
I want to hide the icon from the Highlights panel in the Account object.


Although not explicitly stated in the documentation, Account Hierarchy icon depends on Show View Hierarchy link on account pages setting in Account Settings. For hiding it , this option needs to be unchecked.
Checkout this article for more info.
PFB screenshot of the same :

